# ComboBox with Vaadin Grid and ComponentRenderer and the Empty Grid

Tags: combobox, grid, vaadin7, renderer

I hope this post can help me.
My problem that when I use ComponentRenderer, then the grid appears empty.
The used vaadin version 7.6 and the used ComponentRenderer is 1.0.3 as it is recommended to be.
If I did not use ComponentRenderer, then the grid appears but the combo box is not appear.

What could be the reason?

Below is the used code:

```
    Object itemId = container.addItem();    
    container.getContainerProperty(itemId,"ID").setValue("1");
    container.getContainerProperty(itemId,"Dependent MPI").setValue("200.300");
    container.getContainerProperty(itemId,"MPI Type").setValue("Antenna");
    container.getContainerProperty(itemId,"Approval").setValue(ApproveReject);
    this.getColumn("Approval").setRenderer(new ComponentRenderer());
```

Regards
Bilal

Answer (score 0):

```
Object itemId = container.addItem();    //1
container.getContainerProperty(itemId,"ID").setValue("1");//2
container.getContainerProperty(itemId,"Dependent MPI").setValue("200.300");//3
container.getContainerProperty(itemId,"MPI Type").setValue("Antenna");//4
container.getContainerProperty(itemId,"Approval").setValue(ApproveReject);//5
this.getColumn("Approval").setRenderer(new ComponentRenderer());    //6
```

I believe you are trying to add a column "Approval" in line 5. Shouldn't it be:

```
   Column approvalColumn = container.addColumn(...);
   approvalColumn.setRenderer(...);
```